# Foreach array with objects

Tags: php, arrays, loops, foreach

I'm receiving this from a service:

```
stdClass Object ( 
             [TipoProdutoVO] => Array ( 
                                   [0] => stdClass Object ( 
                                          [entityStatus] => CURRENT [ID] => 23 [TIPO] => [DESCRICAO] => LENTE ACABADA [PARA_VENDA] => [INATIVO] => )
                                   [1] => stdClass Object (
                                          [entityStatus] => CURRENT [ID] => 32 [TIPO] => [DESCRICAO] => LENTES FABRICADAS [PARA_VENDA] => [INATIVO] => )
                                       )
                 )
```

A array with strClass objects.

I need to loop these values and set some objects like:

```
foreach ($res->ObterTipoProdutoParaWebSiteResult as $tipoproduto)
            {
                $tipoProdutoVO = new TipoProdutoVO();
                $tipoProdutoVO->ID = $tipoproduto[$x]->ID;
                $tipoProdutoVO->DESCRICAO = $tipoproduto[$x]->DESCRICAO;

                $lista_tipo_produtos[$x] = $tipoProdutoVO;
                $x++;
            }
```

And as expected, since the result is a object, it will loop once, returning me one value and not two as expected.

As it is a list of TipoProdutoVO objects I've tried to:

```
foreach ($res->ObterTipoProdutoParaWebSiteResult->TipoProdutoVO as $tipoproduto)
```

But I get this error:

> Fatal error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array in
>   /opt/lampp/htdocs/lglentes/application/controllers/pedido.php on line
>   30

How can I solve this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you get when you do a var_dump on $res->ObterTipoProdutoParaWebSiteResult->TipoProdutoVO?

Comment: Do you receive an array of objects or an object that contains an array?

Comment: try this `var arr = array($res->ObterTipoProdutoParaWebSiteResult);`

Comment: Also, can you post the code where you call the web service?

Comment: @AllisonC it returns this: Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [entityStatus] => CURRENT [ID] => 23 [TIPO] => [DESCRICAO] => LENTE ACABADA [PARA_VENDA] => [INATIVO] => ) [1] => stdClass Object ( [entityStatus] => CURRENT [ID] => 32 [TIPO] => [DESCRICAO] => LENTES FABRICADAS [PARA_VENDA] => [INATIVO] => ) )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Off the top of my head, you're using the "foreach' wrong. You're using it as a "for".
Try this:

```
foreach ($res->ObterTipoProdutoParaWebSiteResult as $tipoproduto)
{
    $tipoProdutoVO = new TipoProdutoVO();
    $tipoProdutoVO->ID = $tipoproduto->ID;
    $tipoProdutoVO->DESCRICAO = $tipoproduto->DESCRICAO;

    $lista_tipo_produtos[] = $tipoProdutoVO;
}
```

Comment: That is corret...thanks a lot Ayman...terrible lack of attention =)

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like what you're trying to do is the following:

```
foreach ($res->ObterTipoProdutoParaWebSiteResult->TipoProdutoVO as $tipoproduto)
{
      $tipoProdutoVO = new TipoProdutoVO();
      $tipoProdutoVO->ID = $tipoproduto->ID;
      $tipoProdutoVO->DESCRICAO = $tipoproduto->DESCRICAO;
      $lista_tipo_produtos = $tipoProdutoVO;
}
```

That will loop through the array that is set on the object property 'TipoProdutoVO'